# Python Compare Dataframe columns and replace with contents based on prefix

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, match, multiple-columns

Still relatively new to working in python and am having some issues.

I currently have a small program that takes csv files, merges them, puts them into a data frame, and then converts to excel.

What I want to do is match the values of 'Team' and 'Abrev' from the data frame columns based on the prefix of its values, and then replace Team column with 'Abrev' column contents.

```
Team         Games  Points  Abrev
Arsenal      38     87      ARS
Liverpool    38     80      LIV
Manchester   38     82      MAN
Newcastle    38     73      NEW
```

I would like it to eventually look like the following:

```
Team  Games  Points  
ARS   38     87      
LIV   38     80    
MAN   38     82      
NEW   38     73
```

So what I'm thinking is that I need a for loop to iterate through the amount of rows in the dataframe, and then I need a way to compare the contents by the prefix in column Abrev. If first three letters match then replace, but I don't know how to go about it because I am trying not to hard code it.

Can someone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you already have the Abbreviation column in the data can’t you just drop the team column and rename the Abbr column? If that isn’t the case you can create an Abbr column from the team column using ‘df[‘Team’].str.slice’

Comment: This would be in the event that there isn't an abbreviation for the Team name to match with. I'm trying to compare the contents, almost like a partial string match. I just want to compare the abbreviation value with the first three letters in the string 'Arsenal', I'm just not sure how. @GauravTaneja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `apply` operation to get the desired output.

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df['Team'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Team'] if row['Team'][:3].upper()!= row['Abrev'] 
                       else row['Abrev'],axis=1)
df.drop('Abrev', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This gives you:

```
Team  Games  Points  
ARS   38     87      
LIV   38     80    
MAN   38     82      
NEW   38     73
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I meant to do, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` is what you are looking for
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df['team'] = df['Abrev']
df.drop('Abrev', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.to_excel('output.xls')
```

Comment: I already have this done. I want to work with the columns, as stated above.